# Passing a customized object to Scala template

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, scala-template

I have an object profileModel in my profile package and my profile.scala.html file have following code

```
@(model: ProfileModel)
```

when I compiles, it is giving an error **recursive value model needs type**

But when I moved this class to models with my application.conf as

```
ebean.default="models.*"
```

it works.
My guess is scala compiler automatically adds models.* to class path at the time of compilation

**Is there a way to make this work without moving the class back to models package ?**

I am using play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, if your `ProfileModel` exists in `profile` package correct declaration in the view should be:

```
@(myProfile: profile.ProfileModel)
```

And '*yes*', Play imports automatically all `models` and `controllers` (and also other well known types), but if you want to use any type in custom package (or ie. imported lib) you need to use full qualified path to it.